# Visualisation of intermediate activations in keras: 'History' object has no attribute 'Model'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have this function to generate a neural network:

```
def create_network(): 
  model = Sequential()

  model.add(Input(shape=(150,150,3)))
  model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=3,strides=(1, 1),activation='relu'))
  model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

  model.add(Flatten())
  model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))

  model.add(Dense(1, activation='relu'))

  model.compile(optimizer = 'rmsprop',
                   loss = 'binary_crossentropy', 
                   metrics = ['accuracy'])
  return model
```

and then I call the model:

```
network = create_network()
```

Then I find the model:

```
def fit_model(X_train, y_train, network=create_network()):
  model = network
  history = model.fit(X_train,
                      y_train,
                      epochs=2,
                      validation_data=(X_test, y_test),
                      batch_size=32,
                      verbose=2
                      )
  return history
```

and call this function:

```
model = fit_model(X_train,y_train)
```

I want to visualise the intermediate activations in this model (i.e. every channel in every intermediate activation), for a random image.

So I have this code:

```
images = []
for img_path in glob.glob('test_image*.JPEG'):
    image1 = mpimg.imread(img_path)
    open_file = image1 / 255
    resize = cv2.resize(open_file,(150,150))
    print(resize.shape)
    images.append(resize)
  
plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
columns = 5
for i, image in enumerate(images):
    plt.subplot(len(images) / columns + 1, columns, i + 1)
    plt.imshow(image)

print(network.summary())

layer_outputs = [layer.output for layer in model.layers[:]]
activation_model = model.Model(inputs=model.input, outputs=layer_outputs)
activations = activation_model.predict(np.expand_dims(images[0]), axis=0)
```

When I run this I get the error:

```
'History' object has no attribute 'layers'
```

So then I thought ok I'm meant to run this on the network architecture with the layers itself, and not the model that's been fit, so I changed the last three lines to:

```
layer_outputs = [layer.output for layer in network.layers[:]]
activation_model = network.Model(inputs=network.input, outputs=layer_outputs)
activations = activation_model.predict(np.expand_dims(images[0]), axis=0)
```

And I get:

```
AttributeError: 'Sequential' object has no attribute 'Model'
```

Then I thought maybe initially I should be reading in the layers into layer_outputs, but then using the model in the activation_model:

```
layer_outputs = [layer.output for layer in network.layers[:]]
activation_model = model.Model(inputs=model.input, outputs=layer_outputs)
activations = activation_model.predict(np.expand_dims(images[0]), axis=0)
```

But I get:

```
'History' object has no attribute 'Model'
```

Could someone show me where I'm going wrong to visualise my intermediate activations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `model.fit` actually returns a history object and not your model itself. Check the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model?version=nightly#fit):

> A History object. Its History.history attribute is a record of
> training loss values and metrics values at successive epochs, as well
> as validation loss values and validation metrics values

It does not have any layers etc. Try something like this:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

def create_network(): 
  model = tf.keras.Sequential()
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, kernel_size=3,strides=(1, 1),activation='relu'))
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'))

  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='relu'))

  model.compile(optimizer = 'rmsprop',
                   loss = 'binary_crossentropy', 
                   metrics = ['accuracy'])
  return model


def fit_model(network=create_network()):
  model = network
  history = model.fit(tf.random.normal((50, 150, 150, 3)),
                      tf.random.normal((50, 1)),
                      epochs=2,
                      validation_data=(tf.random.normal((50, 150, 150, 3)), tf.random.normal((50, 1))),
                      batch_size=32,
                      verbose=2
                      )
  return history, model

history, model = fit_model()
layer_outputs = [layer.output for layer in model.layers[:]]
activation_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=model.input, outputs=layer_outputs)
activations = activation_model.predict(tf.random.normal((1, 150, 150, 3)))
```